# Trigonometry - 'Find all solutions to the equation'

Tags: trigonometry

I have 3 questions to solve for trigonometry, and I'm not sure of the process to solve them.  They are:

Find all solutions to the equation:

- $4 \sin 2x = 2.4$ $\forall$ $0 ≤ x ≤ 2\pi$
- $2 \cos 2x = 1.3$ $\forall$ $0 ≤ x ≤ 2π$
- $3 \tan 2(x + \frac{\pi}{3}) = 6$ $\forall$ $0 ≤ x ≤ 2\pi$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: The sine/cosine/tangent functions are periodic. This means that over a sufficiently large interval, you will have repeating y-values for different x-values. To get the intuition, you should plot/graph your functions, like $4\sin 2x$:

[image]

$2\pi$ is roughly equal to $6.3$. Look at the interval from 0 to $6.3$. Do you see how there are multiple x-values for the same y-values? For example, for $y=1$, there are three points that look like they'll satisfy the equation.

For actually obtaining the computational answers themselves, it's just two or three steps of rearranging and simplifying to find the first answer. Then use the period of the function to find out when it'll hit that point again.